# "of" before a function argument in swift 3

Tags: swift, function, swift3, arguments

What is the usage of the word "of" before a function argument in swift 3?

Comment: It changes the external name for the argument.  without `of` you'd call it with `neighbors(cell: myCell)` and with `of` you call `neighbors(of: myCell)`.  If you want no label, replace of with `_`, then `neighbors(myCell)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an argument label:

```
func someFunction(argumentLabel parameterName: Int) {
    // In the function body, parameterName refers to the argument value
    // for that parameter.
}
```

Check the [documentation on function declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) for more information:

> The use of argument labels can allow a function to be called in an
>   expressive, sentence-like manner, while still providing a function
>   body that is readable and clear in intent.